# How can I place a button below my ProgressBar?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to place this button right below my ProgressBar. Using this xml, the button just disapears. i tried using `android:layout_below`, but that didn't work at all. Is there some other way?

Relevant XML code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
        android:secondaryProgress="0"></ProgressBar>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="20pt"></TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use LinearLayout and put weight to each view to get desired dimension or you can useConstraintLayout and align views as you desired.   androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Simple Linear layout as suggested by 'alokHarman'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
        android:secondaryProgress="0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="20pt"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Happy Codding !!